# Error in DocumentBuilderFactory fact = new DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();?

Tags: java, itext

It states DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance cannot be resolved to a type. 
Here are the codes:

---

```
 public static void replaceXfaStream(String src, String xml, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException,        
       ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
                                  new FileOutputStream(dest));
    pdfStamper.getWriter().setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
    XfaForm xfa = new XfaForm(pdfReader);
    DocumentBuilderFactory fact = new DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    fact.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = fact.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(xml));
    xfa.setDomDocument(doc);
    xfa.setChanged(true);
    XfaForm.setXfa(xfa, pdfStamper.getReader(), pdfStamper.getWriter());
    pdfStamper.close();

}
```

---

Thanks so much!

Comment: "cannot be resolved to a type" is an import problem. What are your imports?

Comment: import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.*;

Comment: import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

Comment: and import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.XfaForm;

Comment: `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()` is already return a new instance. Why is there a keyword `new` in front of it?

Comment: I think that I have imported everything I need.

Comment: Please edit your original question, do not post additional information in comments, which are very difficult to parse!

Comment: That solved it.  Thanks so much.  You guys are awesome!

Comment: @SiKing - sorry, this is my first time to post a question here.  Will do better next time.

Comment: Even though your problem is solved, please edit your post, for the next person who comes along with the same question.

Comment: I have updated the orig post.

Comment: No, you have not.

Comment: Sorry.  Really new to this.  It's ok now.